# already install command tool lines but I cannot run make command

Tags: gcc, makefile, terminal

I am trying to install tabix and I've already install command lines for Xcode on my Mac. However, when I run 'make' they response like this and the result that I've still finish installing.

```
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -fPIC -o tabix main.o -L. -ltabix -lm -lz
```

I'm just quite new on MacOS and terminal. So, thanks if you have any advices for me.

Comment: What is the exact output when you run `make`?

Comment: You ran "make" and it invoked that `gcc` command`. That command should build an executable file called "tabix". Do you have that file now?

Comment: thank you, guys ^^ I've already install it by using "homebrew".